# After blurring image using GaussianBlur and subtracting, I have more non-zero pixels

Tags: python, opencv, gaussianblur

I'm trying to check if two images are the same, by subtracting them one from each other.
I'm checking the number of non-zero pixels using cv2.countNonZero.
The problem is, that before doing any changes to the images, I'm getting about 3000 non-zero pixels and in the new image (created by the subtraction) I can see all these pixels, but after I'm using the gaussian-blur (cv2.GaussianBlur(image1,(3,3),0)) I'm getting about 6000 non-zero pixels, but the new image is all black.

here is the code if my description is not clear:

```
image1 = cv2.imread(path1)
image2 = cv2.imread(path2)


#Gaussian Filtering
gaus_image1  = cv2.GaussianBlur(image1,(3,3),0)
gaus_image2  = cv2.GaussianBlur(image2,(3,3),0)

gaus_diff = cv2.subtract(gaus_image1, gaus_image2)

print(str(cv2.countNonZero(cv2.cvtColor(gaus_diff, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY))))
cv2.imshow('gaus_diff.png', gaus_diff)
```

What can cause this behavior?
Does it make sense that a black image has so many non-zero pixels?
if yes, is there another way to verify that an image is all black?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. The answer to why you can't see it:

Considering that pixels take a value between 0-255 in grayscale, for 0 difference two pixels must take the same value. As a result of Gaussian blurring, the pixel values ​​converged. For example, let's be the pixels p1 and p2 in two pictures in the same coordinate. Before Gaussian blur, the values ​​were p1 = 330, p2 = 301 diff (p1, p2) = 29, while after Gaussian blur their values ​​were p1 = 315, p2 = 313, that is, diff (p1, p2) = 2. As the value of 29 in grayscale gives a much whiter image than the value of 2, it seems clearer.

2. The answer to having more nonzero value:

The purpose of Gaussian blur is to reduce the number of target edges to obtain a smooth image. When you do this, the values ​​of the pixels converge and you get a smoother transition. However, this does not mean that similar images will have the same value at the same pixel coordinates. A unique smooth process is applied to the picture and each pixel value is reassigned to the picture according to their neighbor pixels. In fact, the result you get confirms exactly this. You cannot observe exactly because the pixel values ​​are close to each other, but as a result of gaussian, the same pixel counts will decrease.

3. An advise:

There is a more statistical yet simpler way to tell if two pictures are the same.
Find the mean and standard deviation values ​​for each RGB channel with (means, stds) = cv2.meanStdDev (image1) and calculate the values ​​and distance of the other image. After a few tries, you can observe how close the same images should give.
"Color channel statistics" term can be used for google search.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try your advice.